# What is the best Object type i can use that represent a site column of type People or Group, which can hold SPUser or SPGroup

Tags: development, event-receivers, ssom, spuser, spgroup

I am working on an Event Receiver for my SharePoint farm 2013. now i have a site column of type "People or Group", and this site column can hold User Name/s OR group names.

so inside my Event Receiver code, i want to check for the item type an based on it assign the site column to a varaible as follow:-

```
 SPListItem currentItem = properties.ListItem;

 string initial = "";
 SPUser orderOwner = null; 
       if (currentItem.ContentType.Name.ToLower().Contains("p"))
          {
              initial = "P";
              orderOwner = currentItem["ProjectOwner"] != null ? (SPUser) currentItem["ProjectOwner"] : null;
           }
       else if (currentItem.ContentType.Name.ToLower().Contains("s"))
          {
                initial = "S";
                orderOwner = currentItem["SalesOwner"] != null ? (SPUser)currentItem["SalesOwner"] : null;
          }
       else if (currentItem.ContentType.Name.ToLower().Contains("c"))
          {
                  initial = "C";
                  orderOwner = currentItem["CancellationOwner"] != null ? (SPUser)currentItem["CancellationOwner"] : null;
          }
```

now my above code will work as long as the `orderOwner` variable is holding an SPUser, but if the related field (ProjectOwner,SalesOwner,CancellaltionOwner) is holding an SPGroup my code will break. so i am not sure how i can have a variable type inside my Event Reciever, which can hold an SPUser or SPGroup ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can identify whether the value contains a user or a group by following piece of code:

```
SPUser user = null; SPGroup group = null;
var userField = (SPFieldUser)currentItem.Fields.GetField("ProjectOwner");
var userFieldValue = (SPFieldUserValue)userField.GetFieldValue(currentItem["ProjectOwner"].ToString());

// This means the value contains a USER
if (userFieldValue.User != null)
{
    user = userFieldValue.User;
}
else //otherwise the value contains a group
{
    group = web.SiteGroups.GetByID(userFieldValue.LookupId);
}
```

Than check which one is not null and use it